# How to convert T-SQL CASE WHEN STATEMENT to Databricks sparkSQL

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I am trying to code a typical T-SQL CASE WHEN statement in sparkSQL.

The T-SQL CASE WHEN statement looks as follows:

```
SELECT
  *
 ,CASE
    WHEN DatesTestv3.as_of_date = EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, SYSDATETIME())) THEN 'LM'
  END AS 'Last Month End'
from dbo.DatesTestv3
```

My attempt at converting the above T-SQL to sparkSQL is as follows:

```
spark.sql("select *, case when as_of_date = last_day(add_months(current_date(),-1)) then 'LM' END AS 'Last Month End" from table)
```

However, I'm getting the ParseException error.

I'm sure it's probably a simple syntax issue.

Therefore, any thoughts on how to convert the T-SQL to sparkSQL?

Comment: The case expression should be a selected column, it's a syntax error to implement it as a table, from a case expression makes no sense here or in any RDBMS

Comment: Hi @Stu, thanks for getting in touch. The column that I'm selecting is called as_of_date.

Comment: @Stu, I have updated the question - hopefully to make more sense

Comment: your revised question is missing a *select*

Comment: Hi @Stu, I have updated the revised question with the 'select'

Comment: You have some quoting issues. Remove the single quote after the AS and move the double quote to the end of the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my knowledge I have tried the Same CASE Statement in the Pyspark at my end.

I have created the table with below columns.
id , as_of_date , last_month_end

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_date
spark.sql("CREATE TABLE data020 (id INT, as_of_date DATE, last_month_end STRING)
data = [
(1, "2023-06-01", "MA"),
(2, "2023-06-01", "MA"),
(3, "2023-06-01", "MA"),
(4, "2023-06-01", "MA"),
(5, "2023-06-01", "MA"),
(6, "2023-06-01", "MA"),
(7, "2023-06-01", "MA"),
(8, "2023-06-01", "MA"),
(9, "2023-06-01", "MA"),
(10, "2023-06-01", "MA")
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["id", "as_of_date", "last_month_end"])
df = df.withColumn("as_of_date", to_date(df.as_of_date))
df.write.mode("overwrite").insertInto("data020")
```

[image]
The CASE statement I have tried is some thing like this.
I have tried in 2 different ways.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import last_day, date_sub, current_date, when
data = spark.table("data_dry")
data = data_dry.withColumn("Last Month End", when(data.as_of_date == last_day(date_sub(current_date(), 1)), "LM").otherwise(None))
data_dry.display()
```

And

```
result = spark.sql("""
```

SELECT *,
CASE
WHEN as_of_date = last_day(date_add(current_date(), -1)) THEN 'LM'
ELSE NULL
END AS `Last Month End`
FROM data_dry
""")

result.display()

[image]
Also you can try with the **`Date_trunc`** function too.